Matrix multiplication notation in Hayashi Econometrics
The question is verify that $X'X/n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i x_i x_i'$ I'm gonna ignore the dividing by n. My problem is if $X$ is a $m \times n$ matrix then $X'X$ is a $n \times m$ matrix multiplied by a $m \times n$ matrix giving a $n \times n$ matrix. Whereas $x_i$ (I'm assuming) is the ith column vector so $x_i x_i'$ is a $m \times 1$ column vector multiplied by a $1 \times m$ row vector giving a $m \times m$ matrix. Then you sum up all i matrices still giving you a $m \times m$ matrix. Is this a typo? or am I missing something?

Perhaps you assume incorrectly  and xi is row. Normally your observational unit are indexed i and are rows in designmatrix.

Wouldn't that still just give me a scaler instead of a n by n matrix?

No it would not see my answer.

Page 6 of Hayashi introduces the notations: $X$ is a $n\times K$ matrix, namely $n$ rows and $K$ columns, and $x_i$ is a $K\times1$ vector of regressors for observation $i$. Thus,
$$\underset{(n\times K)}X = \begin{bmatrix}x_1'\\\vdots\\x_i'\\\vdots\\x_n'\end{bmatrix}$$
Note that $X'X$ is a $K\times K$ matrix. For each observation $i$, $x_ix_i'$ is also a $K\times K$ matrix. Summing over all $n$ observations, we have $X'X = \sum_{i=1}^nx_ix_i'$.

Let $X$ be a $3\times2$ matrix.
You can do row-partitioning
$$X^\top X = \begin{bmatrix}x^\top_1\\x^\top_2\\x^\top_3\end{bmatrix}^\top\begin{bmatrix}x^\top_1\\x^\top_2\\x^\top_3\end{bmatrix} = [x_1\  x_2 \  x_3] \begin{bmatrix}x^\top_1\\x^\top _2\\x^\top_3\end{bmatrix} = \sum_i x_i x^\top_i$$
note that $x_i^\top$ is row $i$ written as a row vector and $x_i$ is row $i$ written as column vector. The convention is therefore that non-transposed vectors are column-form (but may still be a row in the original design matrix) whereas transposed vectors are row-form.
You get the sum of 3 matrices of dimension 2 $\times$ 2. Just as $X^\top X$ is $(3 \times 2)^\top (3 \times 2) = 2 \times 2$
Or you can do column-partitioning
$$X^\top X = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \ \ x_2\end{bmatrix}^\top\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \ \ x_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x^\top_1 \\ x^\top_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \ \ x_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1^\top x_1 & x_1^\top x_2 \\ x_2^\top x_1 & x_2^\top x_2\end{bmatrix}$$
The first approach gives you the matrix multiplication as a sum of outer products the other approach gives you the matrix product as a matrix of inner products.
